# Tibetan word "sur"

Tags: tibetan-buddhism

I am reading a transcript of a talk given by a Tibetan lama, and the word 'sur' is used.  What is it?  Does it have something to do with food offering?

Comment: Can you copy-and-paste to quote from the transcript, to include the context, maybe a paragraph or two?

Answer (score 1):

sur = burnt food offering (Wylie transliteration = bsur). See
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sur_offering

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer this question without the context of the word use.
The [Tibetan and Himalayan Dictionary](http://dictionary.thlib.org/internal_definitions/public_term/127136) defines sur (སུར) as meaning "to whom", but in combination with other words it has totally different meanings, for example sur dug (སུར་དུག) = disease, and kha sur (ཁ་སུར) = date tree.

Answer (score 0):

"Tsok" is a Tibetan Buddhist feast offering, could that be what is meant?
See the [Rigpa Wicki explanation](http://www.rigpawiki.org/index.php?title=Tsok).